# Interleaving two threads such that one of the thread gets null when called putIfAbsent of concurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

can someone explain the interleaving of two threads such that one of the thread gets null when two threads call `putIfAbsent` of `ConcurrentHashMap` in Java?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you read the what it returns? It's not returning the new value as many people assume. *"Returns: the previous value associated with the specified key, or null if there was no mapping for the key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with the key, if the implementation supports null values.)"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the javadoc of [`putIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-):

> **returns:**
>   the previous value associated with the specified key, or null if there was no mapping for the key.

So the first thread attempting to put the value in the map will always have `null` returned to it.

Comment: Funny thing, I had looked at that text and the javadoc multiple times and somehow hadn't noticed that they weren't 100% the same... Sorry about that.